# Slope tool output has artifacts

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

So I've tried using the slope tool for a DEM using an appropriate Z-factor and the output is smooth, but it seems to be over-estimating slope angle.  I would prefer to reproject the DEM (to NAD 83 UTM Zone 9), and run the same analysis, but the output has line artifacts: [image]

I've tried calculating statistics and using bilinear interpolation, but to no avail.

Comment: What coordinate system is the original DEM in?  If it's a geographic coordinate system, the slope will be wrong.

Comment: when you reprojected did you use bilinear resampling type? Also when you are displaying the raster, you may have done a bilinear projection but it is displaying as nearest neighbour?